# C++ map bracket operator in libstd++

Tags: c++, dictionary, gcc, implementation, libstdc++

I know that the C++ map bracket operator is non-const. But does the gcc implementation  actually mutate the map if we call m[key] where key already
exists in the map m?

More specific question: can we continue to rely on other threads having access to m to be able read data from m if one thread does a non-const bracket operator?

Answer (score 2):

> More specific question: can we continue to rely on other threads having access to m to be able read data from m if one thread does a non-const bracket operator?

No, you can't. The containers in the standard library are not thread-safe by themselves. You will need code around them to make access to them thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that but my specific question was whether libstdc++ can guarantee that thread-safety for bracket operator with key known to the map.

Comment: @duli, if a map is not being modified by any thread, you should be able to access its contents in multiple threads without any problem. If any of threads has the potential to modify its contents, it's best to use a [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to access/modify the map.